# display data in sharepoint services 3. 0 dashboard from SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sharepoint

i want to display the SQL server data which is in table form into the SHarepoint.
I dont have sharepoint 2007/2010
I just have SHarepoint services 3.0 and sharepoint designer 2007
please help.
I think business data catalog cant be used in this version.
IS it true ?
do i have to go for paid version ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint designer to create a webpart that shows sql data. Look at the following **[article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010100908.aspx).** YOu cannot use that data in another way (i.e. as a column in a list or something linke that, you need the BDC for that).